# Write data to different sheets of the same xlsx

Tags: r

I would like to know if there is some way to write several variables to different sheets of the same `xlsx` file.

I know that I can append new sheets to an existing file:

```
write.xlsx(x = df,                      
           file = "df.xlsx",
           sheetName = "Data Sheet 2",
           append = TRUE)
```

But, I wouldn't like to write this code for each sheet. Is there any command which allows to create an `xlsx`, adding different data to different sheets directly?

Comment: Have a look at the `openxlsx` library: [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `openxlsx` library can do this.

```
library(openxlsx)

# iniate workbook object
wb <- createWorkbook()

# add 2 worksheets to the workbook object, arbitrary names
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 2")

# some arbitrary data, can also be data.frames
x <- matrix(1:10, 5, 2)
y <- matrix(11:20, 2, 5)

# write data to worksheets in the workbook object
writeData(wb, 1, x)
writeData(wb, 2, y)

# save the workbook to a file
saveWorkbook(wb, "2sheets.xlsx")
```

Comment: You can also can also use the `write.xlsx` function from `{openxlsx}` as follows:

write.xlsx(list("Sheet 1" = x, "Sheet 2" = y), "2sheets.xlsx")

Comment: Do you guys think that your solution also works [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78143875/16762740)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the library writexl to perform that. See an example below on how to do that. To generate multiple sheets directly, you need to put elements into a list, and then call writexl::write_xlsx using that list as an argument. If you would like to customize the names of the sheets, you can pass the names() argument to the list.

```
library(writexl)

##create a list of data frames
list_of_data_frames <- lapply(1:10, function(i){
    data.frame(rnorm(1000))
})

##Add names to the list: these will be converted to sheet names in the workbook
names(list_of_data_frames) <- sapply(1:10, function(i)paste0("sheet_",i))

##Write to file
writexl::write_xlsx(list_of_data_frames, "data_frames_to_excel.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list function to grab the data into one "x" and just use `write_xlsx` as usual.

```
list_data <- list("sheet 1 name" = data1,"sheet 2 name" = data2, "sheet 3 name" = data3)

write_xlsx(list_data,directory path)
```

Comment: Hi @Thoriq, welcome to SO. Your solution sounds interesting, but you should add the reference to the package name (writexl), as you are proposing a solution with a different package of used by OP (xlsx).

Comment: hi @hamagust, thanks for your revised. yes, the package that I used is "Writexl"